# Media element skips some items on playlist

Tags: c#, media

I have a media player that must play a list of items. User can select one of them so items must be selectable, on the other side all of them can play in order. But when i wait for playing in order, saw that madia player skipped some items. For example;

```
1 -> is played
2 -> is played
3 -> is skipped
4 -> is played
5 -> is skipped
6 -> is skipped
7 -> is skipped 
8 -> is played
```

I can not understand the cause of this problem. Have an idea?

this is my media element;

```
   <StackPanel x:Name="PlayerStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <MediaElement x:Name="Player" 
                      MediaOpened="Player_MediaOpened"      
                      MediaEnded="Player_OnMediaEnded">
        </MediaElement>
   </StackPanel>
```

After first item selected, selectionchanged code runs;

```
    void ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation()) this.InvalidateVisualState();

        PlayView();

        selectedItem = sender as Selector;
        ContentItem pc = (ContentItem)selectedItem.SelectedItem;
        if (pc != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pc.AudioFilePath))
        {
            Player.Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, "../Assets/" + pc.AudioFilePath);
            Player.Play();
        }
        else
            Player.Source = null;           
    }
```

When the first audio item ended, Player_OnMediaEnded method is called
I want to increase selectedindex programmatically, after this event, selection changed runs again.

```
    private void Player_OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ticks.Stop();
        ticks.Tick -= ticks_Tick;
        Player.Stop();
        if (this.itemListView.SelectedIndex != contentItems.Count-1)
        this.itemListView.SelectedIndex += 1;
    }
```

With debug, saw that, after one audio file is ended, mediended is called more than one. And also this calling count is constantly changing.

Why my code makes this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I was using a duration slider, when media player ended it must be also ended. But in some case, they can not be synchronized, so duration slider cant work correctly for the queued audio item, immediately it finishes for the next item and skip the others.